# filtrar por colunna hacia sql server

Tags: c#

Necesito poder realizar una consulta en la cual debo filtrar por columna, en la cual tengo serial, fecha, entre otros, en fin, que la consulta me arroje resultados que estén dentro de esa columna.

El código en c# que estoy utilizando y que me funciona es éste:

```
String consulta = "select Date_Timer, Serial,Polo_1  from Electronico where Serial = '" + textBox1.Text +"'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, cnn);
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

Cuando ejecuto con este código

> [image: cuando ejecuto con este codigo]

Quiero sustituirlo por este código y me falla al mostrar los datos:

```
String consulta = "select Date_Timer, '" + textBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.Text + "'from Electronico where Serial = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, cnn);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

Cuando ejecuto con este código:

> [image: cuando ejecuto con este codigo]

Me podrian ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo asi:

```
String consulta = "select Date_Timer, Serial," + comboBox1.Text + 
                  "from Electronico where Serial = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Comment: hola, perfecto gracias no conocia eso, como lograr corregir eso.

Comment: logre hacerlo de esta manera no se si es una manera correcta

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IN_Serial", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = textBox1.Text;
 para la fecha, no creo que aga falta por que no adminte edictar , pues bien, en combobox solo admitiria lo asignado en el. Alguna sujerencia.

Answer (score 1):

No añadas las comillas simples (`'`) en la cadena de consulta:

```
String consulta = "select Date_Timer, Serial, " + comboBox1.Text + " from Electronico where Serial = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Fuera de tu pregunta en específico, te recomiendo que no construyas tus consultas así, es un código propenso a [inyecciones SQL](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=inyecciones+sql&ia=web). Te invito a que investigues más sobre el tema y sigas practicando y mejorando tus habilidades con este magnífico lenguaje ;)